# NativeBase Drawer swipe not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code?  When I run the simulator it runs fine but when I swipe to bring up the  content it doesn't show up.  The drawer wont work. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Drawer } from 'native-base';
import { Navigator, View } from 'react-native';

export default class DrawerExample extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
toggled: false,
store: {},
theme: null
};
}

toggleDrawer() {
this.state.toggled ? this._drawer.close() : this._drawer.open();
}

openDrawer() {
this.setState({toggled: true});
}

closeDrawer() {
this.setState({toggled: false});
}

renderScene(route, navigator) {
switch(route) {
  default: return null;
}
}
configureScene(route, routeStack) {
return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight;
}
render() {
return (
    <Drawer
      ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
      type='displace'
      content={<View style={{backgroundColor: '#000', height: 1000}} />}
      onClose={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)}
      onOpen={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
      openDrawerOffset={100}
      >
        <Navigator
          ref={(ref) => this._navigator =  ref}
          configureScene={this.configureScene.bind(this)}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
        />
      </Drawer>
      );
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this with `panOpenMask={<value>}`. 
I tested it with a value of `.25`.

The [API](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer) says:

> `panOpenMask` (Number) `null` - Ratio of screen width that is valid for
>   the start of a pan open action. If null -> defaults to `max(.05, closedDrawerOffset)`

EDIT:

My full code (on my own project) is:

```
<Drawer
   ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
   content={ navigationView }
   side="right"
   panOpenMask={.25}
>
```

Comment: Great! I used to have `acceptPan={false}` in my project due to my boilerplate. I changed it to `true` and now I can open/close the drawer by swiping. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't know about that one. I'll probably make the switch too. I'd rather have a bool rather than a random number like `.25`. Cheers~

Comment: Can you tell me where in the docs it explains this. I struggled with this and found this post after reviewing the docs. I did not see anything regarding panOpenMask. https://docs.nativebase.io/COMPONENTS.html#Drawer

Comment: Actually I am not sure how someone would go about finding the API you posted.

Comment: @Aaron Sorry, was out of town D: From the NativeBase API link you gave us, the description says `Drawer is used from react-native-drawer` :D